# Inequality involving trigonometry and exponentiation

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, exponential-function

Show that if $ 0\leq x\leq\pi/2 $ $$2^{\sqrt{\sin x}}+2^{\sqrt{\cos x}}\geq 2+\sin x+\cos x \geq 3$$ I encountered this problem when I tried to solve the equation $$2^{\sqrt{\sin x}}+2^{\sqrt{\cos x}}=2+\sin x+\cos x$$ I tried to use $A.M\geq G.M$ but it didn't help or I could not solve it properly.

Comment: Set $x=\frac\pi4$ to check the last inequality

Comment: In the range you have $0\le \cos x \le 1$ so that $\cos x \le \sqrt {\cos x}$. Have you tried the binomial theorem with $2^{\sqrt {\cos x}}=(1+1)^{\sqrt {\cos x}}$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: for $0\leqslant x\leqslant1$
$$2^x\geqslant 1 + x^2$$

Comment: And for the second part, $$(\sin x+\cos x)^2 = 1+\sin(2x) \geq 1.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Very good, Thanks.

Comment: I forgot a (+1) before. It may be interesting to point out that such inequality follows from the concavity of the function $2^{\sqrt{x}}$ over $(0,1)$.